# Obtener datos de varias Tablas, según condición

Tags: sql, select, tablas, datos

estoy un poco oxidado en SQL y Actualmente necesito obtener un listado de huéspedes con varios datos desde distintas tablas. Estos clientes pueden tener Company asociada o no, el problema es que si escribo el código como está ahora, solo me muestra los huéspedes asociados a una Company pero no los movimientos de los huéspedes sin Company asociada. Necesito que me muestre los datos requeridos de ambos casos. Espero ser claro desde ya muchas gracias por los comentarios y ayudas!!!

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITYDT.NUMBER AS 'FOLIO',
       HISTHD.PREFIX AS 'DNI',
       HISTHD.FIRSTNAME AS 'NOMBRE',
       HISTHD.LASTNAME AS 'APELLIDO',
       HISTTRN.ROOMNUMBER AS 'HABIT.',
       HISTHD.CHECKIN AS 'CHECK-IN',
       HISTHD.CHECKOUT AS 'CHECK-OUT',
       HISTHD.NIGHTS AS 'NOCHES',
       

           HISTHD.COMPANY,
           CITYHD.NAME AS 'COMPAÑIA',
           CITYHD.STREET AS 'CIF',
 
       HISTHD.CHECKOUT AS 'FECHA FACT.',
           
       CITYDT.AMOUNT AS 'TOTAL FACTURA'
       
       
  FROM VIPFILE, HISTTRN, HISTHD, CITYDT
  WHERE HISTTRN.ORIGCREDIT > 0 AND HISTTRN.VOID <> 'V' AND HISTTRN.HASVOID <> 'Y' 
  AND HISTHD.NUMBER = CITYDT.NUMBER
  AND HISTHD.NUMBER = HISTTRN.NUMBER 
  AND HISTHD.CHECKOUT BETWEEN '{?Enter Lower Checkin Date }' AND '{?Enter Higher CheckIn Date}'
  ORDER BY HISTHD.CHECKOUT
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Deberías de incluir un pequeño ejemplo con los datos y las estructuras de las tablas, y el resultado a obtener, para poder ayudarte de un modo preciso. Además deberías de cambiar la forma de union de las tablas del Where a el On. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: ¿En qué motor de base de datos ejecutas esta sentencia?

Comment: En MS SQL Server 2019 express

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas sobre `COMPANY`, necesitarás un `LEFT JOIN`. Prueba así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITYDT.NUMBER AS 'FOLIO',
    HISTHD.PREFIX AS 'DNI',
    HISTHD.FIRSTNAME AS 'NOMBRE',
    HISTHD.LASTNAME AS 'APELLIDO',
    HISTTRN.ROOMNUMBER AS 'HABIT.',
    HISTHD.CHECKIN AS 'CHECK-IN',
    HISTHD.CHECKOUT AS 'CHECK-OUT',
    HISTHD.NIGHTS AS 'NOCHES',
    HISTHD.COMPANY,
    CITYHD.NAME AS 'COMPAÑIA',
    CITYHD.STREET AS 'CIF',
    HISTHD.CHECKOUT AS 'FECHA FACT.',
    CITYDT.AMOUNT AS 'TOTAL FACTURA'
    FROM VIPFILE JOIN HISTTRN JOIN HISTHD LEFT JOIN CITYDT
    ON HISTTRN.ORIGCREDIT > 0 
    AND HISTTRN.VOID <> 'V' 
    AND HISTTRN.HASVOID <> 'Y' 
    AND HISTHD.NUMBER = CITYDT.NUMBER
    AND HISTHD.NUMBER = HISTTRN.NUMBER 
    AND HISTHD.CHECKOUT 
    BETWEEN '{?Enter Lower Checkin Date }' 
    AND '{?Enter Higher CheckIn Date}'
    ORDER BY HISTHD.CHECKOUT;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo, veo que la tabla `VIPFILE` no la utilizas para nada ,por lo que no es necesario que aparezca en la consulta. Lo que debes hacer es unir las consultas por el campo en común y con el método más adecuado.

Lo habitual es que compartan claves (primaria/foránea) por lo que se realiza un `JOIN`. Si alguna tabla no cumple siempre esta relación, se realiza un `LEFT JOIN`, es decir tomo los datos de la primera tabla los une con los de la segunda y en aquellos campos donde no coincidan aparecerá el valor `null`

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITYDT.NUMBER AS 'FOLIO',
       HISTHD.PREFIX AS 'DNI',
       HISTHD.FIRSTNAME AS 'NOMBRE',
       HISTHD.LASTNAME AS 'APELLIDO',
       HISTTRN.ROOMNUMBER AS 'HABIT.',
       HISTHD.CHECKIN AS 'CHECK-IN',
       HISTHD.CHECKOUT AS 'CHECK-OUT',
       HISTHD.NIGHTS AS 'NOCHES',
       HISTHD.COMPANY,
       CITYHD.NAME AS 'COMPAÑIA',
       CITYHD.STREET AS 'CIF',
       HISTHD.CHECKOUT AS 'FECHA FACT.',
       CITYDT.AMOUNT AS 'TOTAL FACTURA'
  FROM HISTTRN
  LEFT JOIN HISTHD ON HISTHD.NUMBER = HISTTRN.NUMBER
  LEFT JOIN CITYDT ON HISTHD.NUMBER = CITYDT.NUMBER
  WHERE HISTTRN.ORIGCREDIT > 0 AND HISTTRN.VOID <> 'V' AND HISTTRN.HASVOID <> 'Y' 
  AND HISTHD.CHECKOUT BETWEEN '{?Enter Lower Checkin Date }' AND '{?Enter Higher CheckIn Date}'
  ORDER BY HISTHD.CHECKOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

David, Roger muchas gracias por la ayuda.
He tomado el código como me lo han pasado y ha funcionado, lo único que no me muestra es el total de la factura cuando el huésped no tiene Company asignada, me muestra 0.
Así quedó el código.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT HISTHD.NUMBER AS 'FOLIO',
       HISTHD.PREFIX AS 'DNI',
       HISTHD.FIRSTNAME AS 'NOMBRE',
       HISTHD.LASTNAME AS 'APELLIDO',
       HISTTRN.ROOMNUMBER AS 'HABIT.',
       HISTHD.CHECKIN AS 'CHECK-IN',
       HISTHD.CHECKOUT AS 'CHECK-OUT',
       HISTHD.NIGHTS AS 'NOCHES',
       HISTHD.COMPANY,
       CITYHD.NAME AS 'COMPAÑIA',
       CITYHD.STREET AS 'CIF',
       HISTHD.CHECKOUT AS 'FECHA FACT.',
       CITYDT.AMOUNT AS 'TOTAL FACTURA'
  FROM HISTTRN
  LEFT JOIN HISTHD ON HISTHD.NUMBER = HISTTRN.NUMBER
  LEFT JOIN CITYDT ON HISTHD.NUMBER = CITYDT.NUMBER
  LEFT JOIN CITYHD ON HISTHD.COMPANY = CITYHD.ACCOUNT
  WHERE HISTTRN.ORIGCREDIT > 0 AND HISTTRN.VOID <> 'V' AND HISTTRN.HASVOID <> 'Y' 
  AND HISTHD.CHECKOUT BETWEEN '{?Enter Lower Checkout Date }'  
  AND '{?Enter Higher Checkout Date}'
  ORDER BY HISTHD.CHECKOUT
```

Comment: Si esto no es una repuesta a tu pregunta, elimínala y modifica la pregunta original incluyendo esta información, así como un dataset de muestra para hacer las pruebas con phpmyadmin, Exportar. También es importante que incluyas el resultado que esperas obtener para esos datos de muestra y unas fechas de ejemplo. Por un momento pensé que ya tenías la solución...